# GParted does not see my Fujitsu HDD

Tags: hard-drive, external-hdd

I have a Fujitsu HDD and it was working properly for more than a year. But know I am tring to use it with Windows or Ubuntu but none of them can recognize.

I tried refreshing GParted to recognize it but it stays for a long time trying without any luck.

Any way to force 'mount' or copy entire HDD to the internal HDD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that if it's not detected in either Widows or Linux or gparted it's permanently broken.

But to be sure , you can check in your bios, during startup, if the drive is detected there. If you don't see any drive there then it's gone.

If you dont have a bios you can access you can see if the linux detects it at all by typing :

```
dmesg |less
```

, in the terminal to look through the up start log of your computer.
it will contain any harddrives detected during start up of Linux